# Book series about a female protagonist who's transported to another world, where she encounters creatures such as gnomes, witches, and sphinxes

Tags: story-identification, books, isekai

I'm looking for a book series that came out before 2003.

What I remember is that the main character (MC) is a woman who gets transported to another world. There she meets different kinds of creatures such as gnomes, witches, and sphinxes. Some help her and some are against her.

In one or some of the books, the main character falls in love or is bound to a creature from the fantasy world she ended up in. The creature has the ability to take over or possess other people's and creatures' bodies.

In the end, the MC returns to her own world and the creature she fell in love with has kinda followed her by possessing a cat in her world, to still be able to keep in contact with her. Any help would be nice. :D